# A process converging to a certain distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-process, gamma-distribution

How is it possible to build a discrete-time stochastic process so that converges to a specific distribution at equilibrium, for example an exponential distribution or a  gamma distribution ?

Comment: Do you mean a sequence of random variables that converge in distribution to a $\Gamma$ distribution? Or do you mean a Markov chain whose equilibrium is the $\Gamma$ distribution? Or something else?

Comment: I mean a Markov chain whose equilibrium distribution is the $\Gamma$ distribution.

Comment: Trivially, taking $X_n \sim \Gamma$ for all $n$ works. The Markov chain is degenerate in that it does not depend on even $X_{n-1}$, but it is a valid example.

Comment: Yes but there are no correlations between different times. I'm trying to think of a chain with positive correlations between $X_n$ and $X_{n+m}$ that decay as a function of $m$.

Comment: You might be getting confused between "equilibrium" and "limiting" distributions, and [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48262/what-is-the-difference-between-limiting-and-stationary-distributions) might be helpful in demystifying the difference between the two. Your first comment says that you are interested in an equilibrium distribution though your second comment suggests that you want a limiting distribution. I wrote an answer that has both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a characteristic function $\varphi$.
Define the operator $T$ by
$$
T[\psi]=\frac{1}{2}\left(\varphi+\psi\right).
$$
Note that $T$ maps characteristic functions to characteristic functions since any convex combination of characteristic functions is once again a characteristic function.

Define a Markov chain as follows: $X_{0}$ is given and $X_{n+1}$ has
characteristic function $T[\varphi_{n}]$ where $\varphi_{n}$ is
the characteristic function of $X_{n}$.
Since $\varphi$ is a fixed point of $T$, it follows that $\varphi$ is an equilibrium of this Markov chain.

Note that
$$
T^{k}[\psi]=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{k}}\right)\varphi+\frac{1}{2^{k}}\psi
$$
so that this Markov chain also has $\varphi$ as its limiting distribution.

**Answering your question:** you can take $\varphi$ to be the characteristic function of the gamma distribution to achieve your goal.

There isn't really anything special about this construction. It satisfies your requirements, but you could come up with a bunch of other ways to do so.